# wordpress site can not show the icons when visited by domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

When visiting the site by IP, icons can display correctly，like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuI0h.jpg).

But when using the domain, some icons are dead. So ,what's the problem?
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMCon.jpg)

Comment: have you checked your console for errors? the might be some cross site origin errors.

Comment: solved it ，change the wordpress->settings->url